# How to fix API changes in NetworkX?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

While doing a Newton-Raphson power flow study, when i run that command:

```
network.pf()
```

I get that error:  AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'OrderedGraph'

**[#5813] OrderedGraph and other Ordered classes are replaced by Graph because Python dicts (and thus networkx graphs) now maintain order.
****AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute'OrderedGraph'**

How can i fix that matter?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there complete small example thats failing? With import statements etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I updated pypsa and networkx and the problem has been solved. Thanks..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).